# Is there any discussion of a Back to the Future sequel or remake?

Tags: back-to-the-future, sequel

I ask this because it was

> The highest grossing film of 1985, Back to the Future launched one of the most successful franchises in Universal's history, including two theatrical sequels, an animated television series, a theme park ride, toys, comic books, video games and apparel.
>   <sub>http://www.backtothefuture.com/movies</sub>

In addition:

> Following a year-long grassroots effort initiated by this site, the U.S. Library of Congress announced in December 2007 the preservation of the original Back to the Future film by its addition to the National Film Registry.

In other words it was immensely popular.  And the last one was made in 1990.   That is just about the timeframe where Hollywood goes and starts making remakes or sequels to milk the cow more.   Furthermore, you might get a cameo out of Fox or Lloyd before it's too late.

What is the current state of any plans for the franchise?

Comment: I really really really hope not...

Comment: I don't have the actual quote in front of me, but the director made a statement something like *Not in my lifetime*. So, maybe there will be a sequel or a reboot, but none are in production atm. (Didn't make this an answer because the quote might be slightly off)

Comment: “And the last one was made in 1990.” The last *Ghostbusters* film was made in 1989; a remake/sequel/something is due in 2016. We can therefore confidently expect *Back to the Future IV: Back to Back to the Future* in 2017. That’s just basic maths.

Comment: http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_IV - Not gonna happen until Zemeckis and Gale die.

Comment: @Richard:   That link is a gold mine

Comment: Making a sequel would break the chiastic structure of the trilogy!

Comment: VTC: This question is *prima facie* an off-topic questtion about future works.

Comment: @Lexible:   Absolutely not.   *Future works* means you can't ask for (plot, casting, etc) details about future works that will inevitably be revealed when the work is released.   It doesn't mean you can't ask about the state of present day plans and what related production staff might have said already.   "Is there discussion" is a square in the present question.

Answer (score 34):

**TL;DR: No. The rights holders refuse to do a sequel, remake, or allow them to be made.**

[image]

Bob Gale (the co-writer and producer of the original films) has did [an interview with Yahoo](http://web.archive.org/web/20150406105131/https://uk.yahoo.com/movies/back-to-the-future-musical-is-the-closest-well-ever-100103153001.html) where he said

> “Let’s face it, we’ve seen a lot of sequels that are made years and years later and I don’t think I can name one that’s any good,” he says. “That lives up to the originals. I don’t
> think you can recapture it.”

He has no interest in doing a sequel or reboot, or any director's cuts or special editions

> “We’re not going to do Director’s Cuts or make a 3D version or change the special effects. People love them the way they are, we think they’re really good. Let’s not mess with it.”

Additionally, Robert Zemeckis (the director of the franchise) has said in no uncertain terms that [there will be no remake](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/back-to-the-future/remake-sequel-robert-zemeckis/).

> “Oh, God no,” the 63-year-old director told the Telegraph, when asked if – as one of the two rights holders to the original film, along with co-writer Bob Gale – he would ever consider signing off on a remake.

He explains that he and Bob Gale own the rights, and will continue to block the studios from doing so until they die.

> “That can’t happen until both Bob and I are dead. And then I’m sure they’ll do it, unless there’s a way our estates can stop it.

The only new BTTF work you can see is [*Back to the Future: The Musical*](https://www.backtothefuturemusical.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAybaRBhDtARIsAIEG3kmLlziTPhL61y24Jdb1vB_GrXYMcLL87jYp8p8RxsFJP4ZvrTwKNQ0aAlZgEALw_wcB), which is showing at the Adelphi Theatre in London until October 2022.

Comment: This is welcome news!

Comment: I can think of plenty of remakes that were as good or better than the originals. The problem is that you have to take off your [nostalgia goggles](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nostalgia+goggles)

Comment: You mention the musical, but another new BTTF work in the pipeline is [this comic series](http://io9.com/back-to-the-future-is-getting-its-own-comic-series-1716595064), which is going to be co-written by Bob Gale, and which will depict some offscreen events set before/between/during (but not after) the movies.

Comment: @CreationEdge This is definitely true, but I think that the creators are trying to say that you have to know the right time to stop and not try to milk more out of something completed and finished.

Comment: @Hypnosifl About as many I can think of, period. But I'm biased because I only follow and watch ones I'm already interested in. Anything else doesn't make it on my radar.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Well, there's a big collection of remakes [here](http://letterboxd.com/furiouslyalex/list/unnecessary-remakes/) and another one [here](http://www.impawards.com/articles/poster_remakes.html), of the one's I've seen or at least seen reviews of, it does seem like most are not as good as the original. Out of curiosity can you name a few of the ones you're thinking of?

Comment: Re: [Faulty Towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fawlty_Towers) –"The decision by Cleese and Booth to quit before a third series has often been lauded, as it ensured the show's successful status wouldn't be weakened with later, lower-quality work. Subsequently, it has inspired the makers of other shows to do likewise."

Comment: I wish I could +2 this answer +1 for the answer itself and +1 for how pleased the news makes me...

Answer (score 5):

@phantom42 pointed out that that there won't be a **movie** sequel, but it's worth mentioning that [Back to the Future: The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future:_The_Game) continues the story where the movie left off.

Bob Gale *(co-writer and producer of the film)* was involved as a story consultant, and included [several scenarios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future:_The_Game#Development) that he and Robert Zemeckis had originally conceived for the films.  However, the game is not officially considered series canon.

It's a Telltale adventure game, so it's mainly story-driven: anyone can pick it up, even if you don't consider yourself a gamer.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that Back to the Future: The Game was ok in its own right but a big let down as BTTF.

Comment: I'm quite tempted to move this to a comment on phantom42's answer,  but it is probably too long to survive. Would you like to move it?

Answer (score 3):

As Tom Wilson, the actor who played Biff, says in his *Questions Song*:

> Back to the Future IV?
>   **NOT HAPPENING!**

Comment: As funny as this is I don't see why his song would come as an official source to answer this question. Could you expand on it perhaps with some more references?

Comment: @Pureferret, this is a perfectly legitimate source.   Presumably, it means he has no knowledge of plans and also has reason to believe it will never happen (with him).  Also, have a sense of humor.

Comment: Can you replace the video?